# Find fundamental period of a discrete-time signal

Tags: signal, signal-processing

I have the following discrete-time signal:
$$x[n] = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}n)\cos({\frac{\pi}{4}n}), \quad n\in\mathbb{Z},$$
By looking at it, I'd say that the time period of the signal \$x[n]\$ is \$\frac{2\pi}{\frac{\pi}{4}}= 8\$, since the smaller sub-period is \$\frac{\pi}{4}\$. However, is there a more rigorous way to prove this?

Comment: I just graphed this formula in Wolfram Alpha and it doesn't seem to have a period of 8.

Comment: @user1139880: You may have done it wrong. Show us what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One frequency is twice the other and given that the two frequencies are multiplied, you get sum and difference frequencies in the result: -

[image]

Hence, the waveform adopts the period of the lowest frequency because: -

\$\dfrac{\pi}{2}n - \dfrac{\pi}{4} n = \dfrac{\pi}{4}n\$

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/164238

An excerpt from that post:

> If \$p\$ and \$q\$ are periods of \$f(x)\$ and \$g(x)\$ respectively, then any common multiple of \$p\$ and \$q\$ is a period of \$H(f(x),g(x))\$ for any function \$H(u,v)\$, in particular when \$H\$ is addition and when \$H\$ is multiplication. So the least common multiple of \$p\$ and \$q\$, if it exists, is a period of \$H(f(x),g(x))\$. However, it need not be the smallest period.

It is straightforward to prove this: if \$f(x+N)=f(x)\$ and if \$g(x+N)=g(x)\$, then

$$H\bigl((f(x+N)g(x+N)\bigr) = H\bigl(f(x)g(x)\bigr),$$

if such \$N\$ exists.

Periods of the two functions are \$p=4\$ and \$q=8\$, and their common multiple is \$N=8\$, so that is the fundamental period of your discrete-time signal \$x[n]\$.

**Here is the MATLAB code to generate plots.**

```
n = 0:48;
f = cos(pi/2*n);
g = cos(pi/4*n);

figure(1);
clf;

h1 = subplot(6,2,1);
stem(n,f); grid on;

h2 = subplot(6,2,3);
stem(n,g); grid on;

h3 = subplot(6,2,5);
stem(n,f.*g); grid on;

set([h1,h2,h3], 'XLim', [0,48], 'XTick', 0:4:48);
```

**Here are the generated plots.**

From top to bottom: \$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}n)\$, \$\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}n)\$, and \$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}n)\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}n)\$:

[image]